# Display message when user inputs invalid/null email id or password

Tags: html, ajax

Is there a way to display an error message when user inputs invalid details or leave an required field blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `required=""` put it inside `<input>` tag

Comment: Welcome hope it was helpful..!!